# When do C++ DLLs get freed in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, dll, interop

I have a C++ DLL that is loaded into a C# Windows Forms app. I am trying to create an opengl context with the dll, and preserve it for use in the managed app while the dll is unloaded/reloaded. I am using LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary to load the DLL.

Is this possible? If the C++ DLL loads the opengl DLL, will the opengl dll be unloaded if I call FreeLibrary on the DLL that loaded it? And is it safe to store the unmanaged objects that were created by the c++ DLL in managed code and reuse them with the new instance of that DLL?

Comment: Almost certainly this is not possible.

Comment: which part? because I have tried retaining data from an unloaded DLL with a C++ DLL and C++ app, and the data was usable after reloading the DLL. I didn't try an opengl context, but I don't see any reason the situation would be any different. I suppose I should try that same old C++ to C++ test app with OpenGL to confirm.

Comment: I don't expect retaining data from an unloaded DLL really works. What if some of that data refers to global structures? And what about the heap? So long as the heap resides in a different module you may get away with it. Anyway, only you know what your DLL is actually doing. Only you know what this information is. You cannot expect us to know anything at all about it.

Comment: "And what about the heap" - in a previous question I asked, someone told me that memory allocated by a DLL belongs to the process, not the DLL, so that it is safe to reuse it after the DLL is unloaded. Is this untrue? did my last test case work by luck, only because the memory had not been overwritten yet?  "What if some of that data refers to global structures?" - I have gone over my DLL, and tried to make sure that the data structures I am referencing have no pointers to global data. It is possible, but not likely that I have missed one.

Comment: @AlBundy: The memory belongs to the process, but the data structures belong to the DLL.  If you try to pass an object allocated in one DLL to a deallocation function in another, it will get very confused.  Even if it's the same DLL, just loaded a second time.  Because its list of "all allocated blocks" got started over when you reloaded it.

Comment: @Ben: That kind of makes sense.. because in C++ to C++, I was using the same CRT for the app and DLL, which may have kept it loaded when I unloaded my own DLL, but in C#, there is no reason to keep the CRT loaded once I unload my DLL =/

Comment: @David Heffernan: It turns out that this is indeed possible. Alas, it was the global pointers set by the GLEW extension library that failed to stick around after the DLL had been reloaded. Pun Intended =) a call to glewInit() after reloading the dll solved the problem.

Comment: You mean, *appears to* solve the problem. You'd be much better served by doing the job properly.

Comment: what do you mean by properly?

Comment: I mean don't get something from a library, unload the library and then try to continue using that thing

Comment: Ok. I thought you meant something more specific. But finally, although a trivial test case worked, I have been getting an access violation for a certain destructor call in my library, and after stepping through the code, it appears that the object's vtable pointer is no longer valid after reloading the DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OpenGL dl was also loaded with the Load Library call then unloading the DLL will not affect it unless you specifically unload it. If it was loaded automatically by the system then it will be unloaded when you unload the C++ dll. You can use the OpenGL context as long as the OpenGl is not unloaded and the window handle which was used in the creation of OpenGL context remains valid.

But I wonder why don't you call the OpenGL dll directly from your application ?

Comment: This behaviour can be confirmed with this ms example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621(v=vs.85).aspx